# MongoDB Text Search on 50gb dataset index doesn't work with exact phrase

Tags: mongodb

So I've got a 50gb database with about 9 million records. I've followed the [MongoDB Docs on text search indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/), and I've done:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { address: "text" } )
```

The seems to work fine, and when I view my indexes I see:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "address_text",
    "ns" : "db.collection",
    "weights" : {
        "address" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

I can do:

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "123 Fake St" } } )
```

and I instantly get a heap of (unsorted) results that either contain `123`, `Fake` or `St`.

However, I CAN'T do an exact term search:

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "\"123 Fake St\"" } } )
```

Nor can I sort the results using the documentation's `score` suggestion:

```
db.collection.find(
   { $text: { $search: "123 Fake St" } },
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

When I try either of these query takes 30+ minutes, then gives me some sort of "you've run out of memory with this query, please use an index" error.

I feel like I've followed the documentation exactly here, but I'm not getting any results. What am I doing wrong?

Expected result is to be able to search for "123 Fake St" and get the records that, for example, have:

```
[
    { "address": "123 Fake St" },
    { "address": "123 Fake St, CA" },
    { "address": "123 Fake St, CA 20300" },
    { "address": "123 Fake St, MB" },
    { "address": "123 Fake St, Antarctica" }
  ]
```

Comment: You can try the [Text Search with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/). Also, see the [Aggregation pipeline limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine here.

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.collection.createIndex( { address: "text" } )
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "commitQuorum" : "votingMembers",
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591983687, 2),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591983687, 2)
}
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.collection.insert({address:"123 Fake St"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.collection.insert({address:"123 St Fake"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "fake"}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee3be58636d9634736aac95"), "address" : "123 St Fake" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee3be52636d9634736aac94"), "address" : "123 Fake St" }
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "123 fake st"}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee3be58636d9634736aac95"), "address" : "123 St Fake" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee3be52636d9634736aac94"), "address" : "123 Fake St" }
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "\"123 fake st\""}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee3be52636d9634736aac94"), "address" : "123 Fake St" }
```